How Can I Connect to Kafka Bootstrap Server Over SASL_SSL With rdkafka?
I am trying to connect to a message broker using the rdkafka Github, attempting to connect to a Confluent Boostrap Server. However my attempt to get messages fails with authentication failure.
I do not have access to the remote broker server, messages are provided as an "open data" service to the general public.
Kafka bootstrap server: ###.europe-west2.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092
SASL mechanism: PLAIN
SASL config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule
Security protocol: SASL_SSL

My PHP consumer file uses the below configuration using a username and password given to me by the data provider
$conf = new RdKafka\Conf();
$conf->set('group.id', 'myGroup');
$conf->set('bootstrap.servers', '##.europe-west2.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092');
$conf->set('sasl.username', '####');
$conf->set('sasl.mechanisms', 'PLAIN');
$conf->set('sasl.password', '####');
$conf->set('security.protocol', 'SASL_SSL');

The error response given by the rdkafka program:
%3|1729596043.057|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://###.europe-west2.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092/boot]: sasl_ssl://pkc-l6wr6.europe-west2.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092/bootstrap: SASL authentication error: Authentication failed (after 5002ms in state AUTH_REQ)

%3|1729596043.058|ERROR|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://###.europe-west2.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092/boot]: 1/1 brokers are down

%3|1729596043.058|ERROR|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:app]: rdkafka#consumer-1: sasl_ssl://###.europe-west2.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092/bootstrap: SASL authentication error: Authentication failed (after 5002ms in state AUTH_REQ)

The issue appears similar to this Confluent Forum question, I have run the telnet command on the port and it successfully connects.
Does anyone know what I could be missing from my configuration? I have considered adding sasl_jaas_config property but JAAS isn't supported by rdkafka. Needless to say, this Github issue seems to suggest I don't need it, just specifying a sasl_username and password should suffice...
Thanks. New to Kafka.
https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka/issues/2510

I have set up a confluent account and cluster, used the API keys in my PHP code and am successfully able to send topic messages, recieved by my consumer php file. Therefore the issue is likely with the broker I am trying to connect to, unless I've missed something critical that could have been overlooked
